MS microphone setup with NTG5
I have a Rode NTG5 microphone that I use to obtain sound material for videos with the mic boomed or mounted on the camera.
I value the high sensitivity of this microphone, and am looking for an extension of my setup that would allow me to record stereo.
The most flexible approach, as I understand it, would be an MS setup. So I am wondering, .. would it make sense to extend the NTG5 into an MS arrangement? Which figure-8 microphones would make sense here? I record with a zoom F3 device.

It might make sense. All depends on what you record. Combining a camera mounted shotgun microphone with a figure-8 is not often seen, possibly mostly from practical reasons. No reason to not try it though.
One obstacle might be budget. There are few smaller size figure-8 microphones on the market as the demand is quite low. The candidates I see are Sennheiser MKH8030 (or used MKH30), Schoeps MK8 capsule for the CMC system. Both a bit in the "professional" cost bracket. Maybe you could find a rental house allowing you to test. Or there might be other alternatives that I am unaware of.
Another issue might be the mount for the double mics and the effect that will have on weight and handleability of the camera + mics + recorder combination.

Thank you, but these are all quite a bit over my budget I'm afraid. I guess I will abandon the idea of recording MS and get an AT BP4025 instead.
